# Flutter build pipeline takes a long. How can I make it quicker?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-runner

I have a self-hosted GitLab that stores my codes. My flutter project uses this pipeline to build an app bundle:

```
stages:
  - build

cache:
  paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.pub-cache/

image: ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:3.16.3

workflow:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always
    - when: never

build-android:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - flutter
  before_script:
    - export PUB_CACHE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.pub-cache
    - export PATH="$PATH":"$PUB_CACHE/bin"
    - cd src
    - flutter doctor --android-licenses
  script:
    - flutter build appbundle --release
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "<build dir>/*.aab"
    expire_in: 1 week
```

I configured a runner for this project that specially run this building process. The runner config.toml is this:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "<name>"
  url = "<git url>"
  id = <id>
  token = "<token>"
  token_obtained_at = <date>
  token_expires_at = <date>
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

My problem issued when the pipeline triggers, and it starts to build the app bundle. This process takes a long time (near 25-30m) although when I build it on my PC it will do so quickly (near 2-3m). Why it's like this? How can I make it faster?

P.S: Resources of both systems are nearly the same! My PC is MacBook Pro m1 2021 and the runner is a LXC that has 10 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 CPU, 16 GB RAM and 40 GB hard.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an S3 server for the runner to cache files inside it (Alternatively, you can use AWS S3). Then reconfigured runner to use this S3 server by adding these lines:

```
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "<url>"
      AccessKey = "<Access Key>"
      SecretKey = "<Secret Key>"
      BucketName = "<Bucket name>"
```

Then added these paths to `.gitlab-ci.yml` to cache them:

- /root/.gradle
- /opt

Now Gradle build takes near 2 minutes but another operation after building that is called `Preparing "Install Android Emulator..."` takes some time near 10 minutes.